# Changing the column order on a single related list impacting the column order on other related lists

Tags: force.com

Setup:

I have an object my_object__c related to Contact, and I have a bunch of page layouts for contact. The related list for my_object__c is on a subset of those contact page layouts.

Question:

Why is it, when I change one of the related list's column orders on a single page layout, a number of other column orders (for the same object ) on different contact page layouts have also been changed in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you can affect the related lists on multiple page layouts at once if you've (inadvertently) selected the other Page Layouts under

> Apply column information to other page layouts:

[image]